# Mysql and node async.waterfall

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I am trying to find out if the record exists in my database table. If it does not exist there, then I want to add it to my database. I use node and using `async.waterfall`. But something is wrong with my code and I could not find what. It does not add the record to my database. Any suggestions?

```
var mysql       = require('mysql');
var connection  = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'user',
  password : 'password',
  database : 'database'
});


for (var m = 0; m <= (urls.length-1); m++) {
     var Myurl = urls[m];
     var ThisName= TheNames[m];

     //IIFE function. I omitted the error handling for clarity.

     (function(Myurl,ThisName){

        async.waterfall([

          //First find out if the record exists in mydata
          function(next){
          connection.query('SELECT * FROM mydata WHERE UrlLink=?   
                            LIMIT 1',[Myurl],next)
                        },

          //If the record does not exist, put it in mydata
          function(results,next){
          if (results.length==false){
              console.log("New Thing!");
              //Do some stuff here, request(Myurl...) to find TableName.
              var post  = {UniqueUrl:Myurl,ThingName:ThisName,TheName:TableName};
              connection.query('Insert INTO mydata Set ?', post,next);
                                    };
                                };
                         ],

          //Final callback
          function(err, results) {
          connection.end();
                                 };
                       );
     })(Myurl,ThisName);
   };
```

`EDIT`:

I got an error with the suggested answer `TypeError: object is not a function`, at the line `return next()` in the `if statement`. In my real code I actually do something like that (when I use the suggested answer):

```
async.series([
  //First function
  function(callback){
    //Some calculations...
    callback();
 },
  //Next function
  function(callback){
       var i = 0;
       //Loop
       async.whilst(
       function() { return i <= thefooz.length-1; },
       //The innerCallback:
       function(innerCallback){
       //Some calculations where i get urls and TheNames.
async.forEachOf(urls, function(Myurl, m, eachDone) {
  var ThisName = TheNames[m];

  async.waterfall([
    function(next) {
      connection.query(
        'SELECT * FROM mydata WHERE UrlLink=? LIMIT 1',
        [ Myurl ],
        next
      );
    },
    function(results, next) {
      if (results.length !== 0) {
        return next();
      }
      console.log("New Thing!");
      //Do some stuff here, request(Myurl...) to find TableName.
      var post = {
        UniqueUrl : Myurl,
        ThingName : ThisName,
        TheName   : TableName
      };
      connection.query('Insert INTO mydata Set ?', post, next);
    }
  ], eachDone);

}, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err; // or however you like to handle errors
  connection.end();
});
setTimeout(function() { i++; innerCallback(); }, 10000);
}); //close my calculations in innerCallback.
     }, //close innerCallback.

    ); //close asyns.whilst
callback;
   } //close function(callback)

      ], function(error){
        if (error) return next(error);

      });
```

I am really stuck in `callback hell`...

Comment: What r u getting?? Any error?? Whether this line console.log("New Thing!"); is printing??

Comment: @Subburaj I would like to know if my approach is correct in general. Regarding using `async.waterfall`, when quering first and when that query is complete do something else.

Comment: In general, I would suggest using [`async.each()/async.eachSeries()/async.eachLimit()`](https://github.com/caolan/async#eacharr-iterator-callback) instead of using a `for` loop for processing your URL's. Also, you're closing the connection after the first URL has been processed, which doesn't seem right. And I would not compare `results.length` with `false` (even though it'll work).

Comment: @robertklep Ok i see, do you have an example of your suggestions? Then I could accept your answer! Br

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An (untested) version that should do the same, but with some bugfixes and enhancements in terms of leveraging more of `async`'s goodness:

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'user',
  password : 'password',
  database : 'database'
});

// Process all url's in parallel (at the same time). If you to process them
// sequentially (one after another), you can use `async.forEachOfSeries()`
// instead. Or, if you want to limit the number of parallel requests, use
// `async.forEachOfLimit()`.

async.forEachOf(urls, function(Myurl, m, eachDone) {
  var ThisName = TheNames[m];

  async.waterfall([
    function(next) {
      connection.query(
        'SELECT * FROM mydata WHERE UrlLink=? LIMIT 1',
        [ Myurl ],
        next
      );
    },
    function(results, fields, next) {
      if (results.length !== 0) {
        return next();
      }
      console.log("New Thing!");
      //Do some stuff here, request(Myurl...) to find TableName.
      var post = {
        UniqueUrl : Myurl,
        ThingName : ThisName,
        TheName   : TableName
      };
      connection.query('Insert INTO mydata Set ?', post, next);
    }
  ], eachDone);

}, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err; // or however you like to handle errors
  connection.end();
});
```

Instead of using `forEach*`, you can also use `each*`, but since you need the array index as well `forEach*` is more convenient.

Relevant documentation:

- [`async.forEachOf`](https://github.com/caolan/async#foreachofobj-iterator-callback)
- [`async.forEachOfSeries`](https://github.com/caolan/async#foreachofseriesobj-iterator-callback)
- [`async.forEachOfLimit`](https://github.com/caolan/async#foreachoflimitobj-limit-iterator-callback)

Comment: I think the simple act of adding `if(err) throw err;` will probably lead you to the solution!

Comment: @robertklep I got an error `TypeError: object is not a function`. The row is `return next()` which causes it.

Comment: @user1665355 apparently, `.query()` calls the callback with three arguments, not two, hence the error. I updated the code to account for that.

Comment: @robertklep Ah ok! I did an update. I am really stuck in callback hell:P

Comment: @user1665355 it looks like it might be time to split your code into separate modules/functions that you feed to the `async` functions. I usually find that "callback hell" can be resolved (or at least mitigated) by refactoring into smaller parts and proper code indentation (or using a completely different methodology like promises).

Comment: @robertklep Ok! I should. But I am quiet a beginner with node and js... Do you see any obvious mistakes in my edit code?:)

Comment: @robertklep Or I think I got it queit right now, but one last question. If I would like to process my urls in the correct order, what should I use? Now the order is not right... But the urls are correct:) Thanks again!!

Comment: @user1665355 I don't know what "the correct order" is, but if you pass them in the array in the correct order and use `async.forEachOfSeries`, the url's will be processed one at the time in the order in which they appear in the array.

Comment: @robertklep Ok! Thanks so much for all feedback! Have a nice weekend:)